# A word for: "The strongest should help the weakest"?

Tags: single-word-requests, abstract-nouns

Is there a word to describe the concept of "The strongest should help the weakest (members of society)"? Or related concepts like "The strongest will learn faster by helping weaker others", or "The perks of elitism should be paid for in a form of benefit to the weakest".

> Your life of freedom and comfort will have to be paid for. You should be helping others. Simply by the ethical commandment of _______"

Comment: Are you talking of some form of compulsion (they must), or a moral duty (they should feel they must), or altruism (they see a deficiency to help with), or self-interest (if the strongest learn faster, for example)?

Comment: [Chivalry](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/chivalry) is close to this, but it's not really an ethical commandment (any more).

Comment: @Mari-LouA to discourage seeking non English words ... it has now been edited out.

Comment: @Mari-LouA sry! I'mgoing for more coffee!

Comment: 'charity' comes close in it's core essence of 'giving aid to those in need'  .  However, it would be nice to have a more specific term that emphasized the burden that fell particularly on those that had the capacity to be charitble

Comment: [*Noblesse oblige*](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/noblesse-oblige), if used non-sarcastically and democratically. Of course that's two words...

Answer (score 1):

As a single word, "beneficence" may work.  Not to complicate the question, but the word "abundance" fills in the blank and completes the thought.

Answer (score 0):

**humanity**  [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/Humanity)

> 1. Humans considered as a group; the human race.
> 2. The condition or quality of being human.
> 3. The quality of being *humane*, *benevolence*.
> 4. A humane characteristic, attribute, or act.

or *humaneness*  [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/humane)

> characterized by tenderness, compassion, and sympathy for other
>   beings, esp. for the suffering or distressed.

As in:

> "Simply by the ethical commandment[s] of humanity (or humaneness)."

Comment: But this does not focus on the particular benevolent attitude / practice of the strong helping the poor.

Comment: humane: characterized by tenderness, compassion, and sympathy for other beings, esp. for the suffering or distressed.

Comment: Looks better now.

Comment: Empathy and goodness in general does not make a specific good trait to put into practice. .. IMO .. humane means too much to be specific to stronger helping the weakest.

Answer (score 0):

mag·na·nim·i·ty [ˌmaɡnəˈnimədē]
NOUN
the fact or condition of being magnanimous; generosity.- "both sides will have to show magnanimity" - synonyms: generosity · charitableness · charity · benevolence · beneficence · open-handedness · big-heartedness · great-heartedness · liberality · humanity · nobility · chivalry · kindness ·

This word encompasses all of the previously mentioned attributes. Though, I would end the sentence you cite differently. **Your life of freedom and comfort will have to be paid for. You should be helping *others simply* by the ethical *practices* of magnanimity.**